# Opening Command Prompt and Performing Commands

Tags: c#, cmd

First and foremost, this is my first program and I am very new to programming overall outside of HTML and some JS.  That being said, I am building an application that gathers and collects system files to be used for troubleshooting purposes.  I have a basic understanding of what I have done so far, I am just having issues with the dxdiag arguments here:

```
    var process = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    // startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag /whql:on /t %UserProfile%\Desktop\My System Files\dxdiag.txt";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
```

*To clarify, I commented out the hidden line so that I can see what the CMD windows is doing while I build the application.

Now I have looked this up and have found multiple other threads relating to the usage of similar code but cannot figure out why my variant will not work using the arguments that I have included.  That is the block that I bring up CMD and execute the dxdiag command.  I have tested the command itself in CMD multiple times to ensure that it works and it does.  My problem is, the argument above will not execute within the CMD prompt that is initiated.  I am including my full block of code below to give some more context as I will be utilizing an msinfo32 export as well.  It is not executing the commands either (did not expect a different result here).

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    namespace System_File_Collection_App
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
        // DXDIAG Output
        var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag /whql:on /t %UserProfile%\Desktop\My System Files\dxdiag.txt";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        // MSINFO32 Output
        var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/c msinfo32 /nfo %UserProfile%\Desktop\My System Files\";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }

    }
```

The indents screwed up a bit when I copied it over but everything checks out and I am able to run the program.

EDIT: Stripping out the dxdiag arguments and using dxdiag along in the code works perfectly fine.  I used that as a testing point to ensure that the command would actually initiate.  I just don't quite understand why the secondary arguments are not used.

Does NOT Work:

```
    startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag" + "/whql:on" + "/t \"%UserProfile%\\Desktop\\dxdiag.txt\"";
```

Works:

```
    startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag";
```

Comment: What happens if you manually run it form the command line? Also put a space as the first character in the Arguments in quotes, and an @ for the first startinfo.Arguments=@"...

Comment: You might want to switch to PowerShell, which has an actual API.

Comment: The code doesn't know where cmd.exe is located.  Maybe use following option : process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;  The shell is cmd.exe.

Comment: To test whether or not it would properly open CMD, I tested it with this line: startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag";                                                It works perfectly fine, opening a command prompt and initializes the dxdiag command.  That is where I was confused as in theory, adding the dxdiag command arguments should still work:

startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag /whql:on /t %UserProfile%\Desktop\My System Files\dxdiag.txt";

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot spaces between arguments, as this one works fine:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c dxdiag /whql:on /t %userprofile%\Desktop\Examples\New folder\myinfo.txt"
```

Note that the path to folder must exist, otherwise it won't work.